# What is the conventional way of declaring CustomKeywords in Katalon Studio?

Tags: katalon-studio

I am getting a bit confused on how `CustomKeywords` should be declared in Katalon Studio. Should they be declared like normal methods with access modifiers such as public, for example:

```
@Keyword
public void loadApp(int delay){
//some code
}
```

or should they be declared with the keyword `def`:

```
@Keyword
def loadApp(int delay){
//some code
}
```

One other thing I also observed in Katalon Studio is that even when I declared a method private in my `CustomKeyword`, I was able to call it from my test case which is the opposite of what I expected. I thought the private method would only be accessible in my `CustomKeyword` where I defined it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Katalon Studio, you need to use @Keyword annotation to tell the system this is a Custom keyword.

Public or Private will be counted if you use the function as Groovy programming language.

Comment: I know what the `@Keyword` annotation is for, I just wanted to know which way I should be using: `def` to define my `Keyword` methods or the usual way as in any other programming language. Also if **access modifiers** don't make any difference in Katalon Studio, then why use them?

Comment: I am not sure I got you yet. Katalon use annotation to mark the custom keyword and use it inside Katalon such as Test Case design. def or public void is Groovy/Java programming language. @Keyword makes a normal Groovy/Java function becoming its keywords.